Multiple npm sessions on the same Windows session
Anybody knows any easy and handy way to have diferent npm configurations and user for diferent folders? I've got my ~/.npmrc with the global configuration that I need for my job (proxy connection, user & passwd) and I need to set that proxy to null and use diferent login for the folder ~/dev which is my personal folder with personal projects. I even need diferent node version.
Any simple way to do that? I've tried some scripts like the shown bellow and a local .npmrc file on dev folder but they didn't work.
function cd {
    param([string]$path)
    Set-Location $path
    if ($PWD.Path -like "*\dev*") {
        $env:NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG = "$PWD\.npmrc"
    } else {
        Remove-Item Env:NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

